# Unable to cast HttpRequestMessage.Properties["MS_RequestContext"] as OwinHttpRequestContext at build time but valid at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, casting, owin

I'm trying to manually fiddle with a property of my `MS_RequestContext` during Controller Activation inside my WebApi's CompositionRoot.

My Create method receives a `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` argument.

I can drill down request to grab

```
request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"]
```

Properties is a `dictionary<string,object>`  That object will be an OwinHttpRequestContext at runtime.

But whenever I attempt to cast, so that I can access the properties on the RequestContext, I get a nasty-gram from Visual Studio

```
(request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"] as OwinHttpRequestContext).Request.Properties;
```

The error that comes back is:

```
The type or namespace 'OwinHttpRequestContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

OwinHttpRequestContext lives inside the System.Web.Http.Owin namespace. My references are all set up. I even have added a using statement for good measure.

So the crazy part is that if I roll back my code that attempts to directly reference `request.Properties`, but instead set a breakpoint inside my Create method, I can -through a watch- execute

```
(request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"] as System.Web.Http.Owin.OwinHttpRequestContext).Request.Properties
```

without issue.  I can confirm that I have no problem modifying the properties at runtime through the immediate window.

```
(request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"] as System.Web.Http.Owin.OwinHttpRequestContext).Request.Properties.Add("Foo","Bar")
```

And the property "Foo" will be available to all of my MessageHandlers.

Why am I not able to perform this same cast at build time?

Answer (score 0):

`OwinHttpRequestContext` is not a public class. That is why you can't use it in code, but debugger can still see it.